# How can I store a unique Core Data database to Parse for each PFUser in iOS 8?

Tags: core-data, parse-platform, unique, store, pfuser

I'm developing an application that has a Login & Sign-Up configuration with Parse.

I'm working with Core Data to store the information. I have four Entities (for example: Favorite Cars, Races, Recent Races, etc.), which are stored on the iPhone and available offline.

I'd like to store this database in Parse so each user that logs in can recover their own copy of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Parse doesn't support this. You should use [Parse Local Data Storage](http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/) instead.

If you want to try anyway, start with the [`FTASync`](https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync) and [`PFIncrementalStore`](https://github.com/sbonami/PFIncrementalStore) implementations. But they're both years-old and unmaintained.

Comment: Thanks Aaron ! Parse local data storage allow me just to store Classes ! How can i find the unique informations stored of the User that will log in ? I mean I would like to have something like a social network "When someone logs in, he'll find his own informations that he created when he signup etc..." I know it's very hard to do it !